# Why the function outputs the same result every time I run it in the r console, which should be different theoretically

Tags: r

Every time I use the same parameters to run the following function, the results are totally the same. However, theoretically, the results should be much different since x_0's are generated randomly.

simshocks & simdiff are functions in package ESGtoolkit to generate the time series with seed=123 by default.

```r
library(ESGtoolkit)
library(CDVine)

rHeston<-function(params,Tdata){
# Input: params - a length-3 vector in the order of \delta,\rho,\sigma_v; Tdata - length of data
# Output: a length-T vector of observations

    delta<-params[1]; alpha<-1-params[2]; sigma_v<-params[3]
    if(alpha<=0) return(list(obs=rep(Inf,Tdata)))
    if(delta<sigma_v^2/2) return(list(obs=rep(Inf,Tdata)))
    x0<-rgamma(1,shape=2*delta/sigma_v^2,scale=sigma_v^2/2/alpha)
    w_t<-simshocks(n=2,horizon=Tdata/252,frequency='daily',method='classic')
    x_t<-simdiff(n=2,horizon=Tdata/252,frequency='daily',model='CIR',x0=x0,theta1=delta,theta2=alpha,theta3=sigma_v,eps=w_t)
    
    x_t_numeric<-unclass(x_t)[-1,1]
    if(sum(is.na(log(x_t_numeric)))>0) browser()

    y_t_shocks<-log(rchisq(Tdata,1))
    y_t<-log(x_t_numeric)+y_t_shocks
    return(list(vol=x_t_numeric,obs=y_t))       
}
```

[the sample output is like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myiWL.png)

Comment: Unfortunately, your code is not reproductible ..

Comment: Hardly possible to help you if your code is not fully reproductible, here, wihout the functions simschoks and simdiff .. noone else can try to run your code and understand where lies the devil ..

Comment: Package ‘ESGtoolkit’ was removed from the CRAN repository. The functions simschoks and simdiff are in this package. I am not sure but `set.seed(0)` could be an explanation.

Comment: According to the image provided, set.seet(0) is only used one time before the next launches, so it should not be the reason ..

Comment: **ESGtoolkit to generate the time series with seed=123** this default seed could explain your issue ..

Comment: Oh I got it! thanks then!